# Screen keeps dimming on Power (Dis-)Connect

Tags: linux, gnome, xorg, gentoo, monitors

I would like to disable the automatic screen dimming when I plug in our out my power adapter. Every time my laptop switches between battery/ac, my screen dims even though I have disabled it in every place I could think of.

gnome-power-manager does not seem to be involved, as killing it makes no difference. However, here are some of my settings:

In my gconf, under the key `/apps/gnome-power-manager/backlight`, I set:

- `battery_reduce`: false
- `enable`: false
- `brightness_ac`: 100
- `brightness_battery`: 100
- `brightness_dim_battery`: 100
- `idle_dim_time`: 3600

Even under `/apps/gnome-power-manager/lowpower`, I unticked all options.

Where else can I control screen dimming?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a hardware thing? My Thinkpad also dims on power disconnect, even before any operating system is loaded.

Comment: @scai My thought exactly. It's likely to be a BIOS setting.

Comment: If it's a hardware issue it should be OS independent. Have you tried a different kernel/distro/OS?